# How to raise an event when i select the same date every time in datetimepicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I want to raise an event when I select the same date in `datetimepicker`. `valuechanged` event is only triggered when the previous and current values are different. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Use CloseUp event instead. It fairs on every close-up. Inside event handler datetimepicker already has new value

Comment: valuechange will trigger only if `VALUE has been change` from word it self it say `Valuechange` so try using some event. like `dtp_CloseUp` this event will trigger if the `Calendar` in dtp is disappear. hope it works.

Comment: Thanks ...@vitalgolub and @Muj that works guys